# Bagel Pico fermi error?

Tags: python, list

*Current code may have more bugs than I see at the moment, but what I am trying to fix is the get_guess() function. At the moment I have coded it to print i in the "for i in range..." because whenever I input a guess, it automatically assumes i = 0 and prints "You can only guess numbers." I'm not sure why, when 0 is part of the list of numbers that it is supposed to check. Any ideas on how to fix this?
 Side note, things are indented correctly, I am just not used to the formatting of this website.*

```
import random

def explain_instructions(): 
print("I am thinking of a number with nonrepeating digits.  You will have 10 attempts to try and guess my number.")
print("'Bagel' will be displayed if no digits are correct.")
print("'Pico' will be displayed if a digit is correct but in the wrong place.") 
print("'Fermi' will be displayed if a correct digit is in the correct place.")

def generate_number(length): 
num_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
random.shuffle(num_list)
secret_num = num_list[0:length]
secret_num = "".join(str(digit) for digit in secret_num)
return secret_num

def give_clues(secret_num, guess):
clues = []
for i in range(len(str(guess))):
    if guess[i] == secret_num[i]:
        clues.append("Fermi")  
    elif guess[i] in secret_num and guess[i] != secret_num[i]: 
        clues.append("Pico")
if clues == []:
    clues.append("Bagel")
return(clues)
print(clues)


def get_guess(length, guess): 
for i in range(int(length)):
    if guess[i] in guess[:i] or guess[i] in guess[i+1:]:
        print("Repeating numbers don't work in this game.")
        return
    elif len(guess) != len(secret_num):
        print("You don't have the correct number of digits.")
        return
    elif guess[i] not in num_list and guess != "":
        print(i,"You can only guess numbers.")
        return
    else: 
        return int(guess)

def play_again(): 
print("Would you like to play again? (Yes/No)")
answer = input()
if answer.lower()== "yes":
    return True
else: 
    print("That wasn't a firm 'yes' so.... goodbye :( ")


print("Welcome to Bagel, Fermi, Pico!")
explain_instructions()
num_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
game_is_done = False

while True: 
print("How long would you like your number to be?")
length = input()
secret_num = generate_number(int(length))
print(secret_num)

max_guess = 0
while max_guess < 10: 
    print("Enter a", length, "digit guess:")
    guess = input()
    if guess == "411":
        print(explain_instructions())
    elif get_guess(length,guess): 
        max_guess += 1 
        clue = give_clues(secret_num,guess) 
        print(clue)

        if clue == ['Fermi'] * len(secret_num):
            print("Congrats! You guessed the correct number!")
            break
        if max_guess == 10:
            print("Oh no! You have run out of guesses. The secret number was:", secret_num)


if not play_again():
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be because you are declaring num_list inside the function 
`generate_number(length)`

So when you ask for num_list outside the function, python has no idea what num_list is. Declaring it as a global variable could solve your problem (haven't tested it, though)
And yes, i = 0 because it's the iterator, not the number you've guessed. If you want to see your guess, write

`print(guess[i],"You can only guess numbers.")`

I would be careful with a couple things, nontheless
 1. Specify that the input has to be a string. If you input an int without the quotes, it crashed (at least for me it crashed), or cast it to string before passing it to the function. It crashed when trying to access the array guess[i]
 2. Be careful with digits that start with 0 (e.g. 02). Casting to int will transform it to 2 if you don't specify otherwise.